Why is it hard to make red and black phosphorous in labs?
I was going through standard states of different elements and found that we take phosphorous as white. The reason was stated that its because its hard to make black and red phosphorous in labs. Why is that so? Being stable shouldn't it actually be easier?

It is hard to prepare standard samples of red or black phosphorus.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/156285/on-what-basis-are-the-prefixes-%ce%b1-and-%ce%b2-given-to-black-phosphorus

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/140494/purification-of-red-phosphorus

Maybe the issue here is consistency.
Red phosphorus is polymeric, so the conditions for creating red phosphorus may result in variable mixtures, i.e., chains with variable length and connectivity. Some conditions like temperature might be easier to control, but others like pressure may make the practical procedure more difficult.
In other words, attempts to make red phosphous will almost certainly generate a mixture, whose exact composition is not defined simply by the name "red phosphorus". This is highly unsuitable as a standard reference.
While white phosphorus is dangerous and hard to work with, as a molecule, its composition is easily defined.
